# wp-login broken admin redirect

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two Wordpress sites in two different languages.

The second one was cloned from the first one. Everything is good and the site looks the same. The issue starts when I log into the admin panel of the second site.

By logging into www.mysite1.com/wp-login.php the redirect will be www.mysite1.com/wp-admin/index.php

Instead the second site redirects me to www.mysite2.com/wp-admin the issue with this is that I have to manually modify the link to edit posts for example. If I go on and clock the posts link in the left sidebar it will take me to www.mysite2.com/edit.php instead of keeping the same structure as site 1 - www.mysite1.com/wp-admin/edit.php

I have to mention that I have already set siteurl and home options to being www.mysite2.com before migrating.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to it in the wp-config.php file. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] should be set to 'www.mysite2.com'